# WPF DataContext Grid Binding

Tags: wpf

I have the following in my XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:StaffViewModel x:Key="StaffViewModel" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StaffViewSource" Source="{Binding StaffMembers}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="StaffGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource StaffViewSource}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="FirstName:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" />
        <Label Content="Surname:" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Surname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
    </Grid>
```

In my ViewModel I have an Observable Collection of Objects that I turn into a CollectionView

```
    private ObservableCollection<Staff> _staffMembers = null;
    private ICollectionView _staffMembersView = null;

    public ICollectionView StaffMembers
    {
        get { return _staffMembersView; }
    }


    public StaffView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _staffMembers = GetStaff();
        _staffMembersView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_staffMembers);

    }
```

but I don't get any Binding appearing in my textboxes

What am I missing?

I have done a similar thing in the past using EntityFramework and Datasets.  This is what I defined on that occasion:-

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:CantileverDataSet x:Key="CantileverDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CabinetsViewSource" Source="{Binding Cabinets, Source={StaticResource CantileverDataSet}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource CabinetsViewSource}">
      <!-- Individual Fields as textboxes here -->
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to data bind a `CollectionViewSource` of a collection to single controls, but you can only bind that to a collection control. Try this instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StaffViewSource}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="StaffGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="FirstName:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" />
                <Label Content="Surname:" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Surname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Your code now defines what each item of the collection should appear... I'm guessing that was what you were aiming for.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand what you are saying although what you have suggested didnt work.  I have done a similar thing using E.F and Datasets, see above.  I'm not sure why that approach worked and this isn't?

Comment: I tested this code before I posted it and it *does* work. I can't tell you why it doesn't work for you... you must have something else interfering with it. Put it in a new project and you'll see that it *does* work.